# Google Real Time Multiplayer Random Match Fails

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games

I published my game 3 days ago, now there are more than 3.000 active players who uses Real Time Multiplayer. Today, nobody is able to create quick game! Playing with friends with invitations is okay but quick game is not working right now! Is there a problem with Google? Is anybody experiencing this also? What should I do? How can I connect with Google?

Comment: If you didn't change anything in your app since yesterday, there might be a problem on the Google's side. You can find all possible ways to contact Google reg. Android Developer issues at http://developer.android.com/support.html.

Comment: Thanks. it is confirmed that the problem is on google side. Hope this will be solved soon otherwise it will be a potential danger for my game.